# Including OpenSSL 1.1.0 .so in Android .aar

Tags: android, ssl, openssl, aar, .so

**Main Question:**

Is there a way for the Android aar build process to include `libssl.so.1.1`?

**Background:**

I'm building a .aar with openssl 1.1.0. 
The shared object openssl outputs is 'libssl.so.1.1' and 'libssl.so' (plus libcrypto, but I will exclude that for now)

When creating a .aar with the shared object, the android library build completes successfully, but is missing the shared object that ends in '.so.1.1'. It is however including other shared objects that explicitly end with '.so'

I'm assuming the android aar gradle task is doing a hard check for files that end with '.so'.

Looking in the android build directory, I see 'intermediates -> jniLibs -> release' contains ALL .so's, including *.so.1.1. 
However, looking in 'intermediates -> library_and_local_jars_jni -> release' it is missing the .so.1.1 files.

More info:

- I'm manually compiling OpenSSL and then dropping the .so files into a Android aar library project. (I've tested they are correct by loading them directly in a apk)
- OpenSSL does not seem to currently support newer NDK's, so I'm using NDK 13.
- Android library project is targeting Android SDK 27 with min of 21
- The Android library project *is* including .so's, just not the one that ends with .so.1.1
- the shared object files are going into the corresponding architecture directories such as 'arm64-v8a'

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the exact problem in the openssl GitHub issue tracker
https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/3902

**With OpenSSL 1.1.0 modify `Configurations/10-main.conf` with the following**

in both sections `"android64" => {` and `"android" => {` you must add `shared_extension => ".so",` like so (make sure it's below `inherit_from`),

```
"android64" => {
    inherit_from     => [ "linux-generic64" ],
    shared_extension => ".so",
    cflags           => add(picker(default => "-mandroid -fPIC --sysroot=\$(CROSS_SYSROOT) -Wa,--noexecstack")),
    bin_cflags       => "-pie",
},
```

**Newer OpenSSL versions (ex. 1.1.1) look to use the following**

`make SHLIB_VERSION_NUMBER= SHLIB_EXT=.so`

Comment: I don't understand how the solution deals with the versioned .sos.